# Cubism js - plotting data between a given time range

Tags: cubism.js

start date/time: 1 Jan 2014  10:30:00
end date/time:  1 Jan 2014  14:30:00
step: every 5 minutes
plot values provided

```
function myMetrics(name) {
    return context.metric(function(start,stop,step,callback){
    var values = [];
    console.log("start = " + start);
    console.log("stop = " + stop);
    return values;
}
```

1. Can this be done using Cubism.js?
2. How do I set the start and end time range? - tried scale
   context.scale.domain([format.parse("2015-03-18 10:30:00").getTime(),
   format.parse("2015-03-18 13:30:00").getTime()]);
   myMetrics function shown above prints different start and end date
3. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the cubism.context() which does help you alter/customize what you are trying to achieve. Something like this:

```
var context = cubism.context()
.serverDelay(new Date(2012, 4, 2) - Date.now())
.step(864e5)
.size(1280)
.stop();
```

for more details check out this post:
[Change scale default in cubism.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927848/change-scale-default-in-cubism-js/10950513#10950513)